# TypeScript types for React component where prop is an array of objects?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My React component has a prop called `propWhichIsArray` which will be an array of objects. These objects will have an `id` which is an ID and `text` which is a string. How can you type this with TypeScript?

```
type Props = {
  propWhichIsArray: {
    id,
    text: string;  
  }[]
};

const Component: React.FC<[Props]> = ({ propWhichIsArray }) => {
  //
```

Im getting an error:

> Property 'propWhichIsArray' does not exist on type '[Props] & { children?:
>   ReactNode; }'.  TS2339

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The main issue is that you're doing `React.FC<[Props]>` instead of `React.FC<Props>`. With the square brackets, you're creating a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) type, whose's zeroth element is of type Props, and then you're having that tuple be the props of your component.

```
interface Props {
  propWhichIsArray: {
    id: ID; // I assume ID is defined elsewhere
    text: string;
  }[]
}

const Component: React.FC<Props> = ({ propWhichIsArray }) => {
```

If this data in the array is being used in other places, you may want to pull it out to its own interface:

```
interface Thingamajig {
  id: ID;
  text: string;
}

interface Props {
  propWhichIsArray: Thingamajig[];
}
```

Comment: That second interface with the strongly typed array as a property in Props is what I always forget to do. Trying to burn that into my brain!